# Read all jars from a outside folder in a maven spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a jar from a Spring Boot maven project .
Now , how can i configure the pom.xml so that it can read all the jars present in a outside folder .
Please note i can add/remove any jars to that folder and want to read the jars on server startup without touching pom.xml . [Don't want to create local repo]

Please share ideas

Comment: You're using Maven. Don't fight it. Put the jars in the local repo.

Comment: This will not help . As multiple people will be working on the project

Comment: Alternatively, try to form a multi module maven project.

Comment: You can have an initial configuration script which publishes the jars in the local repo (one time action for devs). Alternatively use a `system` dependency type (not recommended).

Comment: @rustyx What about client environment then . Need solution other than local repo